# Contain image inside div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, containers

I have a small problem with containing an image in a container. When the image is dragged beyond the container the image hides what I want is for the image to not hide beyond the container I want the image to stop at the container how can I make that possible here is a script.

```js
$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"/></div>');
    $('.imgdrag').draggable();
    $('#fotos').droppable();
    $('.modal-content').resizable();


    $(".download").attr("href", $(this).attr('src'));
    $(".download").show();
  });



});
```

```css
.container5 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="fotos" class="bananas"><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div>
```

```js
$(".bananas").appendTo( $( ".container5" ) );
```

Comment: Have you noticed your snippet throws some errors??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check out the [containment option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) of the draggable jQuery UI widget.**

Here, [I baked a fiddle just for you.](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/2vyct9t3/)

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('img').draggable({
    containment: '.container'
  });
});
```